# Regex for validating a pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have to validate a pattern like : `abc.123456789.123` (example) where I have to check for these things:

1. First *three* should be letters only of **fixed length** (*case insensitive*)
2. Followed by **dot** (`.`)
3. **Numbers** in range **0-9**, **length** should be **9**
4. Followed by **dot** (`.`) and **Numbers** in range **0-9**, **length** should be **3** (*optional*)

Valid Example:

```
 abc.1  
 Abc.123456789  
 aBc.123.123  
 ABC.123456789.12
```

Invalid Exmples:

```
 abc.1.  
 abc..1.123  
 .123  
 abc.123w45678.123  
 abc.
```

What I've tried :

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\.\\d{0,9}\\.\\d{0,3}|[a-zA-Z]{3}\\.\\d{0,9}$
```

As I am new in Regex, I tried the above Regex but it is failing to pass `abc.1.` and `abc..`.

Comment: how come `ABC.123456789.12` and `abc.1` are valid matches as per your stated requirement , clearly a violation

Comment: Please see the lines given above.  abc.123.123 is just example.  length after first dot can be up to 9 and after second dot it can be up to 3. but second dot along with number followed is optional. So, abc.1 and ABC.123456789.12 seems to valid

Comment: you need to be more specific about your explanation

Comment: `^(?i)[a-z]{3}\.[0-9]{9}\.?(?:[0-9]{3})?$` matches your problem statement, but not your examples.

Comment: Your numbered list says you want three letters, then nine numbers, then (optionally) 3 numbers. But now you say the length after the first dot can be "up to 9". Please revise the problem statement with *exactly* what it is you are looking for. When you say contradictory things like this you force us to read your mind, and I'm just no good at mind-reading.

Comment: Also, your given regex has an opening `(` but no closing `)` in it

Comment: Please read the all statements. It will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you want is `^[a-zA-Z]{3}\.[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$`.  It matches your test cases, rather than the rules you gave, because I found your rules to be a bit vague.

I made this regular expression using [regexr](http://regexr.com/), it's a good free tool for constructing and testing regular expressions.

EDIT:
Since you intend to use this regular expression for Java, here is the same regular expression, with escaped backslashes.  `^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\.[0-9]{1,9}(\\.[0-9]{1,3})?$`.

Comment: Replace [1-9] with [0-9]. Also, I believe the first question mark is unnecessary, since the OP meant the last digits are separated by a period if they exist.

Comment: Also, one more thing, since he's asking for Java, you'll need to escape the backslash `"^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\.[0-9]{1,9}(\\.[0-9]{1,3})?$"`

Comment: `I made this regular expression using regexr, it's a good free tool for constructing and testing regular expressions.` I make mine with http://www.regexformat.com which is a better tool (free trial version).

Comment: Might be a very good application, but I'm not working from Windows, and I don't like recommending solutions that would require someone to run non-free software on their system.

Answer (score 0):

> i) first three should be letters only of fixed length (case insensitive)

Case-insensitive (Latin, unaccented) letter: `[A-Za-z]`

You can specify exactly three occurrences either by repeating that fragment twice more, or by using an enumerated quantifier: `{3}`

> ii) followed by dot(.)

The dot is a regex metacharacter, so it needs to be escaped: `\.`.  When put into a String literal, the backslash must be doubled to escape *it*.

> iii) numbers in range 0-9,length should be 9

From your examples, I gather you mean *maximum* length 9.  One decimal digit would be `[0-9]`.  Between one and nine of them would be `[0-9]{1,9}`.

> iv) followed by dot(.) (this is optional)
>
> v) numbers in range 0-9, length should be 3 (this is optional)

The tail of your pattern is optional, but from your examples, (iv) and (v) are not separate options but rather one joint option -- either both are present or both are absent.  Additionally, your examples suggest that you mean a *maximum* of three digits.  You can use the pattern components already discussed to form a sub-pattern for this part; to make it optional, group the pieces together with `(?:)` and make the group optional with a `?` quantifier.

Putting that all together, the (a) pattern for this would be

```
[A-Za-z]{3}\.[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?
```

Or as a string,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{3}\\.[0-9]{1,9}(?:\\.[0-9]{1,3})?");
```

Depending on your requirements, you may or may not want also to anchor the pattern to start of your string (by beginning it with a `^` character) and / or to the end of the string / line (by ending it with a `$` character).  If you do not anchor it to the end of the string, then you may want to append an assertion that the next character, if any, is not another digit: `(?![0-9])`.

Comment: I just corrected the mistake. Second dot combined with number is optional. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to run the regex on http://www.regexplanet.com.  it is passing abc.. and abc.123.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you tried, @user8260690, but the regex tester at regexplanet.com tells *me* that the regex I presented, interpreted as a Java-flavor regex, ***does not*** match either `abc..` or `abc.123.` (the "matches()" column of the result).  It does, however, find that the regex matches an initial substring of the latter (the "lookingAt()" and "find()" columns).  You can modulate the latter via anchoring and/or assertions, as I already discuss in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\.\d{1,9}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

[image]

[See here and click on Java](http://fiddle.re/a1akbn)

Comment: Word characters (`\w`) include decimal digits and the underscore (`_`), which should not appear in the first three characters of the string we're trying to match.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @John.. I actually hadn't noticed your answer, it is similar.

Comment: This is passing the abc.. and abc.123. , which is not valid. I tested on http://www.regexplanet.com

Comment: You may be doing something wrong, since I ran it against all your samples (including these last ones) and give the expected result.  I'll attach a screenshot.